# How can we find active window name in Windows using python?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I have tried using win32gui and pywinauto and they work fine. But if active window is a folder in File Explorer then it gives the name of folder as active window. Is there any way in which we can get File Explorer as active window name?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us your attempted solution (that doesn't give your expected output) so we can identify potential issues with it and guide you towards a solution?

Comment: If you look at the explorer window title, you'll probably see that it's the folder name you're currently in, so "File Explorer" is no valid window name (title). If you want it to be, then don't navigate to any folder :) .